# SFML 2.4.2 getting localBounds before drawing sf::Text object

Tags: c++, text, sfml, text-alignment

I'm working on a project that needs some buttons done with SFML. We're using version 2.4.2. I've managed to accomplish everything but the text alignment, and I'm very confused as to what the problem is.

In order to set the text's alignment, I know that I must set its origin and position properly. Since people may change a button's text, I decided to put the alignment feature into the setString function.

For debugging purposes, I've added a couple of console outputs to show me some of my data. Here's what the function looks like:

```
void rgf::Button::setString(const sf::String & str)
{
    text.setString(str);

    std::cout << "Original Origin: " << text.getOrigin().x << ", " << text.getOrigin().y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Original Position: " << text.getPosition().x << ", " << text.getPosition().y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Original LocalBounds: " << text.getLocalBounds().width << ", " << text.getLocalBounds().height << std::endl;

    auto textRect = text.getLocalBounds();
    auto btnRect = body.getLocalBounds();
    text.setOrigin(textRect.left + textRect.width / 2, textRect.height + textRect.height / 2);
    text.setPosition(btnRect.left + btnRect.width / 2, btnRect.top + btnRect.height / 2);

    std::cout << "New Origin: " << text.getOrigin().x << ", " << text.getOrigin().y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New Position: " << text.getPosition().x << ", " << text.getPosition().y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New LocalBounds: " << text.getLocalBounds().width << ", " << text.getLocalBounds().height << std::endl;
}
```

The console outputs all positons, new and old, as 0 (except new position which returns the expected coords of 50 and 25).

According to what I've found online, as soon as I set the text's string, my text object's localBounds should change. This doesn't happen unless the text has been drawn once already in an sf::RenderWindow.

I made it so that the button's function would set the string to another value, this had the effect of setting the origin and position properly. Setting the string's value in a container's constructor (before it is drawn) doesn't set the origin properly.

I've spent a day on this and I don't understand what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both `sf::Text::getLocalBounds()` and `sf::Text::draw()` call the same internal member to update the geometry, so there shouldn't be any difference. Did you assign a `sf::Font` before updating the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setFont() function was called after the setString() function, which meant that the localBounds were still 0, since there was no font to indicate a width or a height.